# Hibernate: AssertionFailure on entityManager.merge() due to null identifier for collection

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager

I am working with Hibernate in Java and have come across an issue related to the entityManager.merge() operation. I have the following entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="manufacturingitem")
public class ManufacturingItem extends AbstractDocumentItem {

    private long parentId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    private List<ManufacturingItem> subItems = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The main use-case for the parentId is to establish a recursive bill of materials for manufacturing items in my inventory management system.

When I try to add a ManufacturingItem using entityManager.persist(), it works as expected and the item gets saved to the database. However, when I attempt to use entityManager.merge(), I am encountering the following error:

an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier for collection of role (document.disposal.manufacturing.model.ManufacturingItem.subItems)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier for collection of role (document.disposal.manufacturing.model.ManufacturingItem.subItems)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.(CollectionKey.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.(CollectionKey.java:32)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processArrayOrNewCollection(WrapVisitor.java:126)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processCollection(WrapVisitor.java:74)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:92)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processValue(WrapVisitor.java:161)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:53)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.visitCollectionsBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:404)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cloneAndSubstituteValues(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:329)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:278)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:180)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:140)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:314)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:233)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.merge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:152)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.doMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:142)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:122)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:869)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:840)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:253)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:243)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:513)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:547)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:477)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:437)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:571)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:354)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.merge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:149)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.doMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:142)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:122)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:80)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:848)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:834)

From the error message, it seems like there's an issue related to the subItems collection having a null identifier. However, I am unsure of how to approach this problem.

I tried to change the FetchType and cascadeType.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any insights into what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?